# How do I add languages?

Tags: plugins, buddypress, multi-language, language

This may seem like a basic question but I’ve been using Drupal for almost 3 years now and moved to WordPress two weeks ago.

I'm using Buddypress. I just want to add some kind of language tool that syncs (or updates) with the official WordPress website’s translations for plugins and everything throughout the website and let’s users choose between languages (like some kind of language switcher dropdown)

I tried using polylang but it seems to be using a translation of it’s own.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Note that having multiple translations of content, vs translations of buttons/UI are handled separately ( in the sense that UI language is handled by Core and you shouldn't need to download language packs for plugins, and content is not handled at all and requires plugins )

Comment: Also note that plugin recommendations are out of scope here and off topic

Comment: Well, I know Plugins are off topic but i am basically just asking for a way (if possible) to make my wordpress site into two languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using Buddypress. I just want to add some kind of language tool that syncs (or updates) with the official WordPress website’s translations for plugins

Plugins should come with all their language files already, all it requires is setting the language of your site which is done on install. That will set which language the Admin area uses, etc

You can change this under general settings.

Note that BuddyPress may not have been translated into your language of choice, not all plugins have translations, or are built in a way that allows it to be done. This is usually because the plugin author didn't know how, or it did not occur to them to do so

> and everything throughout the website and let’s users choose between languages (like some kind of language switcher dropdown)

Content on the other hand is entirely the domain of plugins. WordPress doesn't have built in multilingual content support

> I tried using polylang but it seems to be using a translation of it’s own.

WP can't translate your content for you, Polylang will be doing its own thing, similar to other multilingual plugins. They also work differently, so one plugin may not work the way you expect depending on how you want translation to work. E.g. do you want a french translation of your posts, or a french sub-site? You need to think about these things while choosing a plugin

> Any Suggestions?

Plugin recommendations are out of scope on this site. If the only aspect of your question was which plugin to use, it would be closed off topic. Remember, you need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer, not just what worked for you this time